# What are the meanings of `B.C. 3/8"` and `6-11/32"`?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm totally ignorant in this area, and probably didn't know how to properly google my question - sorry..

I found this specification here: (https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/ev/EV-RH-IM10-2045B.pdf). My guess is that M10 is the about the metric thread specification (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_metric_screw_thread). But what is the meaning of `B.C. 3/8"` then?

Another question about this spec: (https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/ev/EV-FH-2200-2202B.pdf) - what would be the meaning of `6-11/32"` - it can't be a range, or can it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the hub axle has two different threads on it: M10 probably in the middle and 3/8" either side of the middle section. Not sure what the "B.C." refers to.

[image]

This is confirmed by the fact that the hub nuts (1), which go on the extremities are 3/8", whereas the lock nuts (18), which go on the middle section, are M10.

I think `6-11/32"`means 6 inches and (or plus if you prefer) 11/32 of an inch. Indeed, if you do:

`(6 + 11/32) * 25.4 = 161.77mm`

and the spec says 161mm. You can apply the same logic for 16mm and 6-17/32:

[image]

Comment: B.C. almost certainly stands for 'British Cycle' thread - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Standard_Cycle

Comment: Mad engineering to be using screw threads from two different systems.